# Using fscanf in MATLAB to read in long floating point data

Tags: matlab

I have a txt file where each line is formatted like this:

```
86 0.722932 0.334032 1.19402 0.719591 0.331065 1.19416
```

Using

```
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');
data_column = fscanf(fileID,'%f');
```

converts the data to

```
86 0.7229 0.3340 1.1940 0.7195 0.3310 1.1941
```

How do I keep the original level of precision?

Comment: Just to be sure, did you print the data_column values to the command line? Or did you look into what the values are in a variable editor window? Matlab follows a certain format when printing values and that could be making it seem like your numbers are getting chopped.

Comment: I opened it in the variable editor window, the values seemed chopped there. However after applying brodroll's solution they now print correctly but still appear incorrectly in the variable window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not how you read the text file, but how you display your numbers in matlab. Try issuing

```
format long g
```

before displaying your data_column vector. This is my output:

```
>> format long g
>> fileID = fopen('test.txt','r');
>> data_column = fscanf(fileID,'%f')

data_column =

                        86
                  0.722932
                  0.334032
                   1.19402
                  0.719591
                  0.331065
                   1.19416
```